# Can you set multiple attributes with the DOM's setAttribute function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Let's say I wanted to create an input element using the DOM. Instead of doing something like this

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("class", "my-class");
input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
input.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
```

Is there a DRYer way to write these three lines of code into one line.

I know you could do something like this

```
var attributes = ["class", "type", "checked"];
var values = ["my-class", "checkbox", "checked"];

for (var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
  input.setAttribute(attributes[i], values[i])
end
```

The problem is that is only helpful if you have a boatload of attributes you need to add. If you only have two or three, this is even less DRY.

Is there anyway I can dry up this code?

Comment: Are you looking for a jQuery way too, or only plain vanilla JS?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to reduce the lines from 3 to 1. Any way would work

Comment: @user4703663 jQuery would be much overhead for this [jQuery is always too much overhead]. Why don't you create a function to achieve that?

Comment: In vanilla javascript, the [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method only accepts two parameters for the attribute and value. Other than the jQuery answers listed I don't believe there is a DRY'er way to do this.

Comment: @gautsch how about creating a function? After all, what is jQuery other than a heaping pile of functions?

Comment: @naomik yea absolutely, you can create a function, i was referring to the other jQuery answers on the page. I thought OP was looking for a native method to the element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, You can do using Jquery.

```
$(input).attr(
{
  "data-test-1": num1, 
  "data-test-2": num2
});
```

Comment: Nice. That saves me a lot of typing

Comment: @user4703663 if you're entire goal is to "save a lot of typing" regardless the cost of your codebase dependencies, you're in for a lot of trouble down the road.

Comment: As already @naomik said, is a really bad idea to use jQuery to do this. Use two lines of vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: The question is about Vanilla JS's function and not of JQuery!
You should definitely mention that it's possible via JS and why not use JS solution instead of JQuery.

Comment: @lazycipher moto was to give quick & one possible answer.

Answer (score 12):

I personally think you're taking [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) too far (the three statements do different things, so I don't see how it's not DRY.) But if you must abstract it, just write a function to do it:

```js
var input = document.createElement("input");

function setAttributes(el, options) {
   Object.keys(options).forEach(function(attr) {
     el.setAttribute(attr, options[attr]);
   })
}

setAttributes(input, {"class": "my-class", "type": "checkbox", "checked": "checked"});

console.log(input);
```

Comment: `class` is not a valid attribute name

Comment: @naomik citation needed

Comment: `var i = document.createElement("input"); i.class="nope"; i; //=> <input>`

Comment: You're looking for `className`, not `class`. `class` is also a keyword in ES6, tho `{class: "foo"}` will still function properly.

Comment: @naomik it's also a "future reserved word" in ES5.

Comment: @naomik so my code runs, your example doesn't relate to my code, so you downvote me and copy my answer?

Comment: IE has had a terrible history of supporting setting that attribute. Ultimately, it should be the property being set, though that's beyond the scope of this question. Good point about DRY. That's not an actual concern here.

Answer (score 5):

In jQuery you can do:

```
var $input = $("<input>", {class: "my-class", type: "checkbox", checked:"checked"});
```

Answer (score 5):

[`Element.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) sets a single attribute, but you could easily write a helper function:

```
function setAttributes(elements, attributes) {
  Object.keys(attributes).forEach(function(name) {
    element.setAttribute(name, attributes[name]);
  })
}
```

Usage:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
setAttributes(input, {
  class: "my-class",
  type: "checkbox",
  checked: "checked"
})
```

As other answers say, you could also use `$.attr`. That's great if your project already uses jQuery. If it doesn't, I'd use this function rather than adding a fairly heavyweight dependency for a simple task.

Comment: `class` is not a valid attribute name

Comment: Actually, `className` isn't valid as an attribute. The class won't be set as is. You'd need to change it back to `class` but it'll break in some older IE versions.

Comment: @squint you are right - should have tested. I mistook [`Element.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) for a DOM attribute.

Answer (score 5):

An elegant approach without frameworks or libraries (or even helper functions) is to use:

`Object.assign(element, attributes);`

where the second parameter, `attributes`, is an **object literal** in which:

- the `keys` represent attribute properties
- the `values` represent attribute values.

This means that:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("class", "my-class");
input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
input.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
```

can be written as:

```
const input = document.createElement("input");
Object.assign(input, {class: 'my-class', type: 'checkbox', checked: 'checked'});
```

or, if you prefer:

```
const input = document.createElement("input");

Object.assign(input, {
  class: 'my-class',
  type: 'checkbox',
  checked: 'checked'
});
```

---

### Further Reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 3):

```
var opt = {"class":"my-class", "type": "checkbox", "checked":"checked"};

Object.keys(opt).forEach( function(key){ input.setAttribute(key,opt[key]); } );
```

Comment: `class` is not a valid attribute name

Comment: "Every HTML element may have a class attribute specified." http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/global-attributes.html#classes

Comment: My apologies: I thought the attribute had to be `className` but I've learned otherwise.