# Adding mulitple attributes in the setAttribute

Tags: javascript

If I want to set the `alt` and `scr` attributes using the setAttribute method, do I need 2 lines or can I somehow put all these attributes in a single line?

```js
var imgEl = document.querySelectorAll("img");
imgEl[0].setAttribute("src", "images/image_1.jpg");
imgEl[0].setAttribute("alt", "Image1");
```

I tried this:

```js
imgEl[0].setAttribute("src", "images/image_1.jpg", "alt", "Image1");
```

But this did not work.

Also - Newbie here!!!!  I am just trying concept and not best practices:)

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535595/can-you-set-multiple-attributes-with-the-doms-setattribute-function/30535683

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
  for(var key in attrs) {
    el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
  }
}

setAttributes(imgEl[0], {
  {"attr1": "attr1val"},
  {"attr2": "attr2val"},
  {"attr3": "attr3val"}
});
```

Comment: This won't work. The return value of `setAttribute` is `undefined`.

Comment: You're confusing this with jQuery's `.attr()` method.

Comment: This did not work.  It only set the first attribute in the list.

Comment: @ShawnHayes Updated my answer.